# Google play services stopped Error

Tags: amazon-fire-phone

Google play services stopped Error popping continuously, tried with downgrading google play service and renaming the folder in "Android/data/com.google.android.gms-1.apk" but still this error popping. please help

[image]

Comment: Its continuous crashing, apps close automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a non-stock ROM, you probably need to install a different version of play store apk.
Try this guide http://spinyourfire.com/fire-phone-tips-and-tricks/turn-fire-phone-into-android-phone/

or try to reset your device.

Comment: have  you tried to update the device? This might Solve Your Problem.

Comment: i tried install new apk form playstore. reset my device when i install old version of play services its work fine but when play store update the play service to new update of play service release date 10 November it started this error

Answer (score 0):

this issue is causing due to latest update of google play services. first you have to disable  automatic updates method is given following.
You can stop apps being auto updating in the following way.

Go to Google Play Store app.
Click the menu button and click settings
Select Auto-update apps Under General
Choose Do-not auto update apps

now dont update google play service at any cost if you did you have to face this issue again. now un install your current google play services app and download and install older version which is 7.0.99 apk. it will work better with this.
i also faced same issue in my phone, but after did above method my phone works good..